# How to use Lambda expression to replace string parameter

Tags: c#, linq

Instead of calling:

```
var shows = _repository.ListShows("PublishDate");
```

to return a collection of objects sorted by the publish date, I would like to use a syntax like this:

```
var shows = _repository.ListShows(s => s.PublishDate);
```

What do I need to write to take advantage of the lambda as an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Show> ListShows(Func<Show, string> stringFromShow)
{

}
```

Within that method, use

```
string str = stringFromShow(show);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var shows = _repository.OrderBy(s=>s.PublishDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ListShows method in your repository should look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Show> ListShows(Comparison<Show> comparison)
{
    List<Show> shows = new List<Show>();
    ... code here ...
    shows.Sort(comparison);
    return shows;
}
```

Then you can use a lambda to do the following (it's not as simple as your example, but it works):

```
ListShows((first, second) => first.PublishDate.CompareTo(second.PublishDate));
```